# New Honeywell thermostat wifi install with 3 wire heat only

Tags: thermostat

I have an old 3 wire set up at my current thermostat. Heat only. R - power, W - heat, G - fan. No additional wires to be used for C.

Instructions on the new Honeywell with wifi say that I can use the G for the C. I would need to jumper the G to the Y - cooling.

Since I don't have Y - cooling, can I jumper the G to the W - heat?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace please?

Comment: Right now you can force the fan to run (even if the heater isn't running) simply by pushing the fan switch from "Auto" to "On".  Are you willing to sacrifice that functionality?

Comment: I havent ever used the fan only function. So, im happy to be without it.

Answer (score 1):

With the power to the furnace OFF just remove the wire from the G terminals and connect the wire to the C terminals in the furnace and the stat. Connect R to R and connect w to w. Turn furnace power back ON. Done. No jumpers are needed.

The furnace does not use the thermostat to operate fan during heat. If you jumped G and W the fan only selection on stat would override thermostat temperature setting and would heat continuous until fan only is selected off.

Comment: I just got off the phone with Honeywell and they said the exact same thing. I'll be trying this tomorrow when I get home from Christmas Holiday. Thanks

Comment: @vdm1245 if this worked for you, please stop back by to give it an up vote (for being helpful) and a check mark (for being correct).

Comment: One additional step is needed at the furnace only (not at the thermostat). The G terminal needs to be jumpered to the W terminal. This allows for the fan to engage when the heat comes on. Its been up and running with no issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a G and Y wire? YES – This means your system is compatible with the C-Wire Adapter.

NO – Your system is not compatible with the C-Wire Adapter. Contact Support at 1-855-733-5465 to find a pro-installer.

Connecting G with W will not work

Every system has 24 Volt transformer with R-24 Volt and C-common. (the other site of the transformer.)

In many cases the C wire is feed up to the thermostat but in some cases it is not connected (not used). Double check the cable coming out of the wall for unused C -wire.